# How do I build the TideSDK Developer app?

Tags: tidesdk, ubuntu-12.10

`Ubuntu 12.10`

I'm trying to build the TideSDK developer application (not the SDK itself, that's where it should be. The developer app that is a separate installation, to avoid any confusion).

First, I installed the TideSDK files into `~/.tidesdk` (which is what the documentation says to do on Linux).

Then, I downloaded TideSDK-Developer, unzipped it and had a look at it's `README.md` file, which says I must do the following to build and run the app:

```
python "path-to-TideSDK-sdk/tidebuilder.py" TideSDK-Developer -r -i 'dist,package'
```

So, I enter this:

```
python "~/.tidesdk/sdk/linux/1.3.1-beta/tidebuilder.py" TideSDK-Developer -r -i 'dist,package'
```

But before I hit enter, I just double checked to make sure that is the correct location of `tidebuilder.py`. After `cd`ing into `~/.tidesdk` and using `ls` a few times, I find that that is, in fact, the correct location. So I press `enter`.

This is what I get after doing so:

```
python: can't open file '~/.tidesdk/sdk/linux/1.3.1-beta/tidebuilder.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But clearly, there is such a file/directory. I had checked beforehand to make sure myself.

What am I doing wrong, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to rule this out - can you try expanding the `~` to the absolute path. I ran into something similar for something else I was working on and found that using the actual path fixed the problem.

`~` points to your home directory, so it's likely something like `/home/synaptix/.tidesdk/sdk/linux/1.3.1-beta/tidebuilder.py` - you get the idea.

Comment: That seemed to work - it ran the app. But now I'm greeted with this:

`Couldn't load file:/home/declan/Desktop/TideSDK Developer/runtime/1.3.1-beta/libtide.so, error: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: For anyone with a similar problem, this is because one of the necessary webkit dependencies, libjpeg, isn't installed. Simple fix: `sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-dev`